# ¿Como hacer que no se imprima toda la pagina cuando se solicita?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST){
  echo $_REQUEST["q"];
}
?>
fetch("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?q=HOLA MUNDO';?>").then((res) =>{ res.text().then((txt) => {console.log(txt);})})
```

El problema esque cuando se imprime en la consola me imprime toda la pagina y quiero que solo se imprima el valor de $_REQUEST["q"] y que los dos codigos esten en la misma página.

¿Cómo podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias!

Comment: como que te imprime toda la pagina? a que te referis?

Comment: Lo que obtengo en la consola es esto: <?php
if($_REQUEST){
  echo $_REQUEST["q"];
}
?>
fetch("<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?q=HOLA MUNDO';?>").then((res) =>{ res.text().then((txt) => {console.log(txt);})}), osea todo mi codigo, pero yo lo que quiero es que me imprima solo <?php
if($_REQUEST){
  echo $_REQUEST["q"];
}
?>, lo que vendria a ser "Hola mundo", me va bien si el godigo php esta guardado en otro archivo, pero quiero saber si es posible obtener el mismo resultado teniendo los dos codigos en el mismo archivo

Comment: php se ejecuta del lado del servidor.. js del lado del cliente... todo depende como sirvas el archivo...

Comment: metele un `exit();` despues del print ...